# Sharepoint metadata URL

Tags: sharepoint-server, metadata

I have a sharepoint server 2016 like the one I show in the attached image.

I want, through a java code, to read the metadata of the document `notes.txt`, but I do not know what url endpoint to use for it.

Can someone solve my doubt?

Thank you.

[image: My Sharepoint site]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [SharePoint REST API for files and folders](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn450841(v=office.15)) to get the metadata (or content) of the file.

For your example, the server-relative endpoint URL would be:

- The file with basic metadata:

  `/my/personal/KIEWB/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/my/personal/KIEWB/Documentos compartidos/notas.txt')`
- The file content:

  `/my/personal/KIEWB/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/my/personal/KIEWB/Documentos compartidos/notas.txt')/$value`
- The list item metadata for the file:

  `/my/personal/KIEWB/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/my/personal/KIEWB/Documentos compartidos/notas.txt')/ListItemAllFields`

Comment: ok, thank you.If I want to add metadata from an external application, should I use these endpoints as well?

Comment: Yes. But of course you will also have to authenticate the user first before you are able to use the endpoint.

Comment: You will need the *request/form digest* and it would need a two-phase approach to update the data.

Comment: I can do a get of the metadata, and I can also upload a file with my code, but if I try to change the value of a metadata, it shows me a 403 error.
This is part of the code:

Comment: HttpPut request2 = new HttpPut("http://win-7n6eol508f6/my/personal/KIEWB/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/my/personal/KIEWB/Documentos%20compartidos/notas.txt')/ListItemAllFields");

Comment: String datos="{'__metadata': {'type':'SP.ListItem'},'Equipo':'Miequipo','Departamento':'Sistemas'}"; request2.addHeader("Accept","application/json;odata=verbose"); request2.addHeader("content-Type","application/json;odata=verbose"); request2.setEntity(new StringEntity(datos));

Comment: For updates, you have to provide the `X-RequestDigest` header as well, containing a valid form digest. A valid form digest for the site can be retrieved using the `_api/contextinfo` endpoint, e.g.: `/my/personal/KIEWB/_api/contextinfo`. The info you need is then available in the response at `<responsedata>.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue`. Have a look at [this Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints#WritingData).

Comment: I've done it, but I can´t upload metadata to that url. My problem is uploading metadata to a document hosted in a document library. If I create a list, I am able to upload metadata, but not in a document library. I think it's a problem with the URL, or the type of metadata

Comment: It shows me a "412 Precondition Failed" Error

Comment: Try adding the header `"IF-MATCH": "*"`. It seams to have to do with the ETag which is used to determine the sequence for and managing of concurrent updates. Providing a wildcard `*` will ignore the ETag. Marc Anderson (SPServices author) wrote [a blog post](https://sympmarc.com/2015/10/23/using-etags-in-sharepoint-rest-calls-to-manage-concurrency-control/) about that.

Comment: Thank you, it worked.